# Script called in rc.local only runs second command, not the first

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, startup

I am running a Raspberry Pi with Fadecandy to control LEDs. I have everything set up, i just want to have the Fadecandy server and my exported Processing sketch run at start up.

In rc.local I am calling a script called startup.sh, which contains the following:

```
#! /bin/sh

/home/pi/sketchbook/leds/loading/application.linux64/loading &
/usr/local/bin/fcserver &
```

The second line (the fcserver) is running, the server starts up fine. The first line (the application) does not seem to be running at all.

However, if I call that script (or rc.local) from the terminal, both lines run and the application starts.

I know that if there is an error, rc.local will exit, but that doesn't seem to be the issue when the *second* line is running after the first line doesn't.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What does the application do? if it's a desktop program then `rc.local` isn't the right place/time to start it

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that fcserver runs daemonized - ie forks and disassociates from the running shell, whereas your loading program does not.

What happens when your script is run by init, is that it spawns a new shell (/bin/sh in your case), runs both loading and fcserver in the background in that shell,... and then destroys that shell, which implicitly sends a HUP to all child processes. Fcserver survives that because it is daemonized, whereas loading does not.

You could try prefixing your loading invocation with `nohup`:

```
#! /bin/sh

nohup /home/pi/sketchbook/leds/loading/application.linux64/loading &
/usr/local/bin/fcserver &
```

I am unsure if nohup is available on your Raspberry Pi - I have none to check.

Comment: Why wouldn't the same happen if the script is started manually from a terminal?

Comment: Hmm - that is a good point @ilkkachu! Perhaps it is not the new shell that is the problem, but the one which calls the script? I would test if, after you run the script in the terminal, then quit that terminal, do both still run, or only fcserver